# Where is the origin in a sprite?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, sprite

Where are the origin (x,y) coordinates on a sprite? Is it at the top left? Is it different in cocos2d?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cocos2d, the origin of a sprite is in the middle of the sprite, but you can change that with setAnchorPoint. Also remember the origin (0,0) of the *screen* is in the lower-left, the way OpenGL likes it, not the upper-left the way the Apple libraries like it.